# Given 2 transactions to my smart contact on the same block, how can I tell which came first within the contract?

Tags: solidity, transactions, blocks

My contract requires holding a history of all interactions to it. I have a hook for everything except tokens being sent to the contract — this requires a separate array of history from everything else that I add to manually.

The problem is, I don't know how to order tokens being sent in with the rest of the history. Right now I'm using the balance to find which came first, but it's messy. Is there another way?

Comment: How about having a user approving your contract for how many tokens they want to send it? Then user calls a function on your contract, where the contract itself gets the tokens (using transferFrom) and records the history.

Comment: Not possible unfortunately @eth — this is building on another protocol that just sends the tokens without any hook or function calls to the contract

Answer (score 0):

In Ethereum, transactions are executed in the order they are included in a block. Within a block, transactions are executed in the order they appear, with the first transaction in the block being executed first, followed by the second transaction, and so on.

Therefore, if two transactions are included in the same block, the order in which they are executed is determined by the order in which they appear in the block.

If you want to determine the order in which transactions were executed within your smart contract, you can use the `block.number` and `transaction.nonce` properties. The `block.number` property indicates the block number that the transaction was included in, and the transaction.nonce property indicates the order in which the transaction was included in the block.

For example, if you have two transactions, `tx1` and `tx2`, you can determine which was executed first by comparing their `block.number` and transaction.nonce properties. If `tx1.block.number` is less than `tx2.block.number`, then `tx1` was executed first. If `tx1.block.number` is equal to `tx2.block.number`, then the transaction with the lower `transaction.nonce` value was executed first.

Here is an example of how you can use the `block.number` and `transaction.nonce` properties to determine the order in which transactions were executed within a smart contract:

```
function determineTransactionOrder(
  uint256 blockNumber1,
  uint256 nonce1,
  uint256 blockNumber2,
  uint256 nonce2
) public view returns (string) {
  if (blockNumber1 < blockNumber2) {
    return "Transaction 1 was executed first.";
  } else if (blockNumber1 > blockNumber2) {
    return "Transaction 2 was executed first.";
  } else {
    if (nonce1 < nonce2) {
      return "Transaction 1 was executed first.";
    } else {
      return "Transaction 2 was executed first.";
    }
  }
}
```

This function takes the `block.number` and `transaction.nonce` values for two transactions as input and returns a string indicating the order in which the transactions were executed. It first checks if the `block.number` values are different and returns a message based on which block number is lower. If the `block.number` values are the same, it compares the `transaction.nonce` values and returns a message based on which nonce value is lower.

Comment: It doesn't look like 'transaction' is a special variable in solidity. 'tx' is, but there is no '.nonce' function.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties

Answer (score 0):

you call the function `getTransactionReceipt()` using transaction hash as parameter. The receipt will have a field called 'Index' this field is the position of the transaction inside the block. Then you have to compare this index of both transaction, the lower index means that transaction has executed earlier

Comment: I'm looking for an answer in solidity, that I can call within the contract. I don't think there is a way to get the index of a transaction within a call — let alone the index of a transaction that happened previously

Comment: no , it is not possible. this is because your transaction can't know about other transactions while the block is being constructed. Also your transaction can't know its own index because the receipt is generated upon the `exit` from the `call()`. you can force your contract to execute only 1 transaction per block by adding an `if` condition to it + storage variable and hardcoded revert on second transaction.

Comment: the only variables available during the execution of the contract are the ones in `BlockContext` and the ones in `TxContext` : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/79a478bb6176425c2400e949890e668a3d9a3d05/core/vm/evm.go#L61
there is no transaction index there, neither there is any indication of another transactions executed in the past